# How to fix the Gnome/Unity shortcut for an application?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome

I installed the development version of Gimp, then found it too buggy, so switched back to the Ubuntu repository version.  In doing so, somehow Gnome/Unity/whatever became confused and now fails to open gimp either from the sidebar, the lens thingy, or clicking on an xcf file.

Running `gimp` from the command line works fine, and `which gimp` outputs `/usr/bin/gimp`, which is correct.

How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `locate gimp.desktop` will it output this:?

```
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/gimp:gimp.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gimp.desktop
```

If there are some excess lines starting with `/usr/local/share`, your deinstallation may have failed. Unfortunately there seems to be no command to let the unity-applications-daemon refresh its application cache.

You may achieve this by logging out and in.

Comment: Thanks for your help... it also lists `/usr/local/share/applications/gimp.desktop`... reboot doesn't help.  can I just delete that file?

Comment: Yes, delete it, then you should be fine. Also have a look at the output of `find /usr/share/local/ | grep gimp` - there may be some leftovers that may conflict with the repository version.

Comment: thanks alot, worked perfectly!  btw, it should be `/usr/local/share`, not `/usr/share/local`; so it's safe to delete the `/usr/local/share/gimp` directory?

Comment: Yes, go ahead. It got too late yesterday. Besides, if you install something with `./configure && make && sudo make install`, you should keep the sources to do a later `sudo make uninstall` which will remove all the cruft under `/usr/local/`.

Comment: thanks... I realize I probably should have used checkinstall or some such thing... didn't think of make uninstall... will remember that next time.